# How do I find the order of layers(z-index) rendered in mapbox

Tags: dictionary, mapbox, z-index, mapbox-gl-js, layer

I have several custom layers rendered on the map, how do i find out which layer is top and which layer is beneath.

Suppose i have 20 custom layers rendered on the map, I need to find out which layer is above or below which layer

Answer (score 1):

We can find the order of layers rendered using the map object itself.

log the map object, inside the style property, we have the _order property that contains the array of layers that are rendered on the map.

Entries in the _order array are arranged in z-index ascending order.
The first entry(layer) in _order array is beneath the second entry(layer) in _order array.
that last entry is the top most layer that appears on the map.

eg: **this.map.style._order**